# Raycast on concave MeshCollider

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, collider

So I am trying to detect whether my player camera is inside or outside a concave collider (a tube). My current approach looks like this:

```c#
 void Update () {
    int layerMask = 0x1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tube");
    int maxLen = 1000;
    var camDir = cam.transform.forward;

    RaycastHit hit1;
    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, camDir, out hit1, maxLen, layerMask))
    {
        //Camera is either inside or outside the tube
        Debug.DrawLine(cam.transform.position, hit1.point, Color.green);

        RaycastHit hit2;
        if (Physics.Raycast(hit1.point + camDir, camDir, out hit2, maxLen, layerMask))
        {
            //Ray hits concave tube twice (outside and inside)
            //So camera is definitely outside.
            Debug.DrawLine(hit1.point + camDir, camDir, Color.cyan);
            Debug.Log("Camera is outside!");
        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("Camera is inside!");
        }
    }    
}
```

Theoretically, If both rays collide then we are outside the tube. (One collision on the outside and one on the inside). But somehow Raycasts ignore the outside of the collider and it goes right through. Is there any way to prevent this or maybe a better solution? [image: Note: green line is ray]

Comment: Not totally sure how you have things set up here, but rays can only detect colliders in one direction. Meaning, if you cast from the inside of a collider to the outside, it will not detect anything. Only works outside to inside.

Comment: Ok. So is there any sane way of detecting whether the camera is outside the tube collider?

Comment: What kind of collider do you use? Meanwhile would it work for you to create a convex trigger surrounding your object, and check for collision?

Comment: I use a concave (i.e. not convex) mesh collider. I'll try it and report back.